# Stopping TreeNodeExpanded event handler from executing if .Expand() is used in code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, handler

On an ASP.Net TreeView, we have it structured like this:

```
+ Maintenance
+ Parents
+ Students
+ Financial
```

The TreeView nodes can be expanded with the user clicking on the (+) signs. This TreeView is also expanded from within a code-behind file as well.

In the code-behind is a TreeNodeExpanded event handler which executes when the user clicks on the (+) signs.

In one of the other sub routines in the code-behind there is an .Expand(), but this causes the TreeNodeExpanded event handler to execute. We don't want that event handler to execute when the nodes are expanded with code using .Expand(). For example: The user clicks on Financial (not the + sign) which also happens to be a link that calls a Financial web page. When that page loads, there is a code-behind file that expands the TreeView nodes which is like the user clicking on the (+) sign. This coding causes the TreeNodeExpanded event handler to execute.

Is it possible to stop the TreeNodeExpanded event handler from executing under this scenario? We only want the TreeNodeExpanded handler to execute when the mouse is clicked on the (+) signs and not at any other times.

Comment: One way would be to set a boolean variable just before you call .Expand.  Then, in the event handler, check if that variable is set, and if so, exit out of the handler.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reply. I will try that next week when vacation is over since I work at a small private school. :-)